JPA error: OutOfMemoryError
Tengo un problema en mi proyecto de spring boot relacionado con un OutOfMemoryError.
El problema ocurre un minuto después de iniciar la ejecución del programa. Desde el momento en que se ejecuta el programa, el uso de memoria aumenta progresivamente hasta llegar a un punto en el que se produce el error. Esto es extraño porque hasta hace unos días, cuando lo ejecuté por última vez, no me pasaba.
He estado revisando posibles causas pero nada se ajusta a mi caso. Al leer el seguimiento de la pila del error, veo que el problema está relacionado con Hibernate y luego con JPA. Al revisar pom.xml, veo la siguiente vulnerabilidad spring-boot-starter-data-jpa: https://devhub.checkmarx.com/cve-details/CVE-2024-22233/
El problema parece estar relacionado, pero al revisar las posibles soluciones veo que el problema ocurre en versiones anteriores de Spring Boot:
https://spring.io/security/cve-2024-22233
¿Alguien sabe qué debo hacer?
Este es el seguimiento de la pila de todo el error:
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-04-27T17:32:36.035+02:00 ERROR 11236 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:165) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:610) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:753) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:455) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1342) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1331) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at com.invaldisoft.worldorder_backend.WorldOrderBackendApplication.main(WorldOrderBackendApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:501) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:218) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:188) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtFilter' defined in file [C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\world-order_backend\target\classes\com\invaldisoft\worldorder_backend\security\jwt\JwtFilter.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\world-order_backend\target\classes\com\invaldisoft\worldorder_backend\security\UserDetailsServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userRepositoryJPA' defined in com.invaldisoft.worldorder_backend.user_player_service.user.infrastructure.adapters.UserRepositoryJPA defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:802) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:241) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:563) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:210) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:173) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:168) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:153) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:266) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:240) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:52) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4850) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:845) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:488) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\world-order_backend\target\classes\com\invaldisoft\worldorder_backend\security\UserDetailsServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userRepositoryJPA' defined in com.invaldisoft.worldorder_backend.user_player_service.user.infrastructure.adapters.UserRepositoryJPA defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:802) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:241) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:563) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1441) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1348) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:911) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepositoryJPA' defined in com.invaldisoft.worldorder_backend.user_player_service.user.infrastructure.adapters.UserRepositoryJPA defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1686) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1435) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1441) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1348) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:911) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:689) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:513) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1166) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:563) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    ... 85 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Java heap space
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1775) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    ... 97 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.resize(HashMap.java:710) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:669) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:618) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.internal.SqlAstProcessingStateImpl.resolveSqlExpression(SqlAstProcessingStateImpl.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.SqlExpressionResolver.resolveSqlExpression(SqlExpressionResolver.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.BasicAttributeMapping.resolveSqlSelection(BasicAttributeMapping.java:331) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.BasicAttributeMapping.generateFetch(BasicAttributeMapping.java:384) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.FetchParent.generateFetchableFetch(FetchParent.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.lambda$createFetchableConsumer$3(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:986) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder$$Lambda$1064/0x000000080181ee70.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.visitFetches(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:811) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder$$Lambda$1057/0x0000000801818ef0.visitFetches(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSqlAstCreationState.visitFetches(LoaderSqlAstCreationState.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.AbstractFetchParent.afterInitialize(AbstractFetchParent.java:30) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityResultGraphNode.afterInitialize(AbstractEntityResultGraphNode.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityFetchJoinedImpl.<init>(EntityFetchJoinedImpl.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.buildEntityFetchJoined(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:1380) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.lambda$generateFetch$0(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:1539) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping$$Lambda$1068/0x0000000801827618.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.withRegisteredAssociationKeys(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:1784) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.generateFetch(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:1514) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.generateFetch(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.FetchParent.generateFetchableFetch(FetchParent.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.lambda$createFetchableConsumer$3(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:986) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder$$Lambda$1064/0x000000080181ee70.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.visitFetches(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:811) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder$$Lambda$1057/0x0000000801818ef0.visitFetches(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSqlAstCreationState.visitFetches(LoaderSqlAstCreationState.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.AbstractFetchParent.afterInitialize(AbstractFetchParent.java:30) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityResultGraphNode.afterInitialize(AbstractEntityResultGraphNode.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityFetchJoinedImpl.<init>(EntityFetchJoinedImpl.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.buildEntityFetchJoined(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:1380) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]

Este es mi pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.invaldisoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>world-order_backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>world-order_backend</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.9.10</kotlin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>testCompile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>



puedes agregar la clase com.invaldisoft.worldorder_backend.security.jwt.JwtFilter? solo para revisar que esté normal y no sea la causa del problema

Es demasiado larga para añadir al post, te dejo por aquí el enlace al drive con el .txt de la clase

Yo creo que ese clase filtro no tiene nada que ver. Da la sensación de que hay alguna relación circular en tus entidades. Aquí tienen el mismo problema, puede que te sirva su solución. Yo le echaría un ojo a las relaciones que hayas establecido entre entidades.

Gracias, he probado a cambiar mis @ManyToOne del por defecto EAGER a LAZY y el programa ya funciona, tal y como se indica en el post que has citado. ¡Gracias!

De nada! Puedes añadir tú mismo una respuesta indicando lo que has cambiado. Salud! :-)

Finalmente he podido solucionar el problema gracias al comentario de @RubioRic. Mi programa tiene muchísimas relaciones entre @Entity 's de @ManyToOne y @OneToOne. De alguna forma, y puesto que estas dos relaciones tienen un fetch por defecto en EAGER, se estaba generando un bucle al iniciar el programa que provocaba un OutOfMemoryError.
La solución fue cambiar el fetch a LAZY de todas estas relaciones, con eso ya funcionó con normalidad. Lo único que al no cargarse las entidades relacionadas de los @ManyToOne y @OneToOne, tuve que hacer uso de consultas LEFT JOIN FETCH para extraer las entidades asociadas cuando fuese necesario.

Buenas! Sería interesante que completaras la respuesta con parte del código de las clases afectadas antes y despues de la modificación. :-)

Buenas Rubio, el tema es que no se trata de unas clases en concreto, el proyecto abarca varias decenas de miles de líneas de código. De alguna forma se generaba un bucle entre algunas de ellas por la política EAGER, lo que consumaba en un error de memoria.

Pero puedes poner algún ejemplo, no tienen ni que ser las clases reales. Pon un par de clases, cambiándoles el nombre incluso, con una relación antes y después del cambio. Vamos, como veas ...
